# Piedi di Dalb: Who or what is Dalb?

Tags: meaning, translation

I was reading the [open letter sent to Lukaku by Inter fans](https://twitter.com/RanocchiateBlog/status/1169240326613164032), and stumbled upon this on the very first line:

> Non ti scriviamo in inglese perché speriamo che dall'alto dei tuoi 5 mln di follower non entrerai a contatto con questa spiacevole questione (e perché il nostro inglese è buono quanto i piedi di Dalb).

Who or what is Dalb and why is his/her/its/their legs such a bad thing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "Dalb" is not an Italian word.

Comment: https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalbert_Henrique

Comment: @DaG You're right but for a foreign speaker could be difficult to understand the meaning of the phrase and have a doubt about the word. I'm considering this case borderline, under some aspects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Dalb** is just the diminutive of [Dalbert Henrique Chagas Estevão](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalbert_Henrique) a former Inter player which didn't leave a good memory of himself among Inter's supporters.

In fact in this "letter" fans say that they prefer to write in Italian since their English is as poor as Dalbert's feet, meaning he doesn't have so much technique in touching the ball.